# .net for Win95?

Tags: .net, winapi

During some research in the .net 3.5 symbols I've found a preprocessor directive

```
#if WIN95_SUPPORT
//...
#endif
```

This looks *really* strange to me! It is located in line 13861 in System.Windows.Forms.Control's Control.cs in method *void WndProc(ref Message m)*!

Does any of you know anything about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering that the betas of .NET 1.0 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_list) were released before Microsoft ended support of Windows 95 (31 December 2001) I think is safe to assume that the developers were unsure until some point if they had to support Windows 95 or not.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably left over from previous versions of the framework which were supported on Windows 95 (since it would make sense that the previous codebase be used).

Comment: .NET was never supported on Windows 95.  Only Windows 98 SE and newer.

Answer (score 3):

When .NET 1.0 came out it was originally supported on Windows 98 SE.  So my guess, given the assembly that you found it in, is that it was originally there as a way to switch between the Win9x Win Forms and WinNT (2000,XP,Vista,etc) Win Forms.

Because Win9x and WinNT used different messaging protocols.  If you are not familiar with Windows Messaging it is a way for Win Forms to communicate with the OS for things like drawing, keyboard events, mouse events, and everything else.